# How do I create a 'for' loop in Smarty 2?

Tags: smarty2

I would like to know if it is possible to do something similar to a for cycle using Smarty 2.

I would like to have something like this:

```html
<select>
{for $i from 1950 to 2000 }
   <option value="{$i}">{$i}</option>
{/for}
</select>
```

What function should I use, if any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try {section} as it is described in the [smarty docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl)

By the way: Check the {html_options} function: [html_options docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.options.tpl)

Answer (score 6):

You could use PHP's [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:

```html
<select>
    {foreach item=i from=1950|@range:2000}
        <option value="{$i}">{$i}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*This is an old question and already has an accepted answer, but the answer was basically just a link.  I have posted this as a more complete answer, to avoid future visitors having to trawl the docs to find the relevant example.*</sup>

---

In **Smarty 2**, loops are achieved using the [`{section}`](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl) tag, which covers quite a broad range of use-cases.  To write the equivalent of a PHP `for()` loop, the following syntax is used:

```html
<select>
{section name="i" start=1950 loop=2001}
   <option value="{$smarty.section.i.index}">{$smarty.section.i.index}</option>
{/section}
</select>
```

Note that the `loop` property refers to the number at which Smarty will break out of the loop, so it needs to be 1 higher than the final number you want to iterate over.

---

**ADDENDUM:**
Although this is not directly relevant to the question (which is about Smarty 2), it is worth noting that **Smarty 3** introduced a [`{for}`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.for.tpl) tag, so you can now do the following, which is a lot simpler:

```html
<select>
{for $i=1950 to 2000}
   <option value="{$i}">{$i}</option>
{/for}
</select>
```